# Actions On Google link to Maps

Tags: actions-on-google, android-auto

I am using Actions On Google / Dialogflow to create a custom Google assistant app. I would like to link from my action to Google maps. So the user can be navigated to the suggested location.

An example conversation would be:

User: Where is my nearest post box?
Assistant: Your nearest post box is in London, two miles away, would you like to Navigate there?
User: Yes
---Google Maps opens and with directions running---

I can do this with a phone, because I can use a [Button](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#button) but this use case makes the most sense in Android Auto, which isn't classed as a smart display so doesn't support Buttons.

Is there any way I can show a notification or link out to Google Maps from the assistant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button is the right element to handle this type of behavior. On devices that do not support the screen surface capability, the button will not be shown. As such, there is no way to automatically activate a Maps event, including on Android Auto in particular.